# AlertDialog shows SystemUiVisibility

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am making an android game and i set my SystemUiVisibility with the setSystemUiVisibility to not show the top bar and other system ui's, but now when u die in game i want to show an AlertDialog with the score you have. When i show the AlertDialog it brings the SystemUiVisibility back and i dont want to have that happen. Does someone know how to fix that. Here is the code i am using right now for the AlertDialog:

```
dlgAlert.setMessage("You lost, you hit the right color " + Points + " times");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("You died");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                dlgAlert.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Dialog non-focusable when we create it (so we don't trigger a user-interaction) and then make it focusable after it's displayed.

```
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

//Show the dialog!
dialog.show();

//Set the dialog to immersive
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
context.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());

//Clear the not focusable flag from the window
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Comment: i dont have a getWindow